# How do I get the file path from the content URI for video files?

Tags: android, uri, android-contentprovider

I want to attach images or video files from the Android storage. When I select a video from the gallery, it returns the **content uri path**.

How do I get the **file path** with extension from the content URI?

---

I tried following code, but it returns null in lollipop:

```
void pickVideo() {
    Intent videoIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    videoIntent.setType("video/*");
    startActivityForResult(videoIntent, PICK_VIDEO_FILE);
}


@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    try {
        if (resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK)
            return;

        switch (requestCode) {
            case PICK_VIDEO_FILE:
                Uri videoUri = data.getData();
                String path = getRealPathFromURI(getContext(), videoUri);
                Log.d("Video uri path", "path" + path);
                if (mChooseFileDialogListener != null) {
                    mChooseFileDialogListener.onVideoClick(videoUri, HealthRecordViewModel.FILE_TYPE_VIDEO);
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}


public String getRealPathFromURI(Context context, Uri contentUri) {
    Cursor cursor = null;
    try {
        String[] proj = { MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA };
        cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri,  proj, null, null, null);
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    } finally {
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to get the file path with extension?

You don't. There is no requirement that the user select a piece of content that is saved as a file in a place that you have read access to. And there is no requirement that a `ContentProvider` offer some means of translating a `Uri` to a file path.

Use `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()` to read in the content identified by the `Uri`.

Comment: I am new to android programming. Can you give some example related to this?

Comment: @Pulse: `getContentResolver().openInputStream(videoURI)`.

Comment: openInputStream(uri) return InputStream right? How do i use this and it as an attachment? I have to save obtained file and if i click on the saved file, it should use appropriate app to open.

Comment: *save it as an attachment

Comment: @Pulse: "How do i use this and it as an attachment?" -- use that `InputStream` to copy the content to a file that you control. Then, treat the copy as your attachment. Your rights to the content identified by that `Uri` lapse when your process ends, or possibly sooner. If you switch to `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` on Android 4.4+, you can try using `takePersistableUriPermissions()` to be able to use the `Uri` for longer, but even then, the user could delete the document from wherever it is stored. "Attach" IMHO always means "make a copy".

Comment: Thank you so for the answer. I will try this out.

Comment: Even i am struck with this. If possible can you provide complete example?

Comment: @Harshith: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Documents/Durable

Answer (score 0):

This may help

```
import android.content.ContentResolver
import android.content.Context
import android.net.Uri
import android.webkit.MimeTypeMap
import java.io.File
import java.io.FileOutputStream
import java.io.IOException
import java.io.InputStream
import java.io.OutputStream
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.util.Date
import java.util.Locale.getDefault

/**
 * This class will create a temporary file in the cache if need.
 *
 * When the uri already have `file://` schema we don't need to create a new file.
 * The temporary file will always override a previous one, saving memory.
 * Using the cache memory(context.cacheDir) we guarantee to not leak memory
 *
 * @param context used to access Android APIs, like content resolve, it is your activity/fragment.
 * @param uri the URI to load the image from.
 * @param uniqueName If true, make each image cropped have a different file name, this could cause
 * memory issues, use wisely.
 *
 * @return string value of the File path.
 */
 fun getFilePathFromUri(context: Context, uri: Uri, uniqueName: Boolean): String =
    if (uri.path?.contains("file://") == true) uri.path!!
    else getFileFromContentUri(context, uri, uniqueName).path

private fun getFileFromContentUri(context: Context, contentUri: Uri, uniqueName: Boolean): File {
    // Preparing Temp file name
    val fileExtension = getFileExtension(context, contentUri) ?: ""
    val timeStamp = SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", getDefault()).format(Date())
    val fileName = ("temp_file_" + if (uniqueName) timeStamp else "") + ".$fileExtension"
    // Creating Temp file
    val tempFile = File(context.cacheDir, fileName)
    tempFile.createNewFile()
    // Initialize streams
    var oStream: FileOutputStream? = null
    var inputStream: InputStream? = null

    try {
        oStream = FileOutputStream(tempFile)
        inputStream = context.contentResolver.openInputStream(contentUri)

        inputStream?.let { copy(inputStream, oStream) }
        oStream.flush()
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    } finally {
        // Close streams
        inputStream?.close()
        oStream?.close()
    }

    return tempFile
}

private fun getFileExtension(context: Context, uri: Uri): String? =
    if (uri.scheme == ContentResolver.SCHEME_CONTENT)
        MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getExtensionFromMimeType(context.contentResolver.getType(uri))
    else uri.path?.let { MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(Uri.fromFile(File(it)).toString()) }

@Throws(IOException::class)
private fun copy(source: InputStream, target: OutputStream) {
    val buf = ByteArray(8192)
    var length: Int
    while (source.read(buf).also { length = it } > 0) {
        target.write(buf, 0, length)
    }
}
```